# Can I define a function by using `NIntegrate`?

Tags: integral-equations

Here I have a expression with formula like $$C\left(j \right)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{f\left(k \right)e^{-kj}dk}$$Is it possible to define this function `C[j_]` with variable $j$ in MMA?

Comment: Have a look at `FourierCoefficient[f[k],k,j]]==2 Pi c[j]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Either $i$ is missing in the OP or it is not a Fourier transform.

Comment: @yarchik You' re right,  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MMA SE; absolutely! If you want to do it numerically, as your title suggests, you’d actually want to use `NIntegrate`:

```
C[j_] := NIntegrate[f[k] E^(-k j), {k, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

However, `C` is a built in symbol (that Mathematica uses for constants appearing in solutions to equations), so I’d recommend choosing a different name.

Note: You could also attempt to get Mathematica to solve it exactly with `Integrate` instead—same syntax, but you’d want to do it outside of a `:=` function definition, otherwise it would try to find the exact solution afresh each time you called your function. You could either evaluate the `Integrate` expression and then start typing in the output cell, or you could do something like `Block[{j}, C0[j_] = Integrate[...]]`, since `=` evaluates its rhs before setting the lhs, in contrast with `:=`, and `Block` here temporarily clears `j` and so ensures `j` is uncontaminated by any active definitions for `j` you might have floating around. Note this kind of thing is only necessary for the less-used and somewhat riskier `=` definitions.

Comment: Thank you, these help me a lot!